# How do you check if a folder exists in Google Cloud Storage using Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am having an issue trying to determine if a 'directory/folder' exists in Google Cloud Storage.

I know there is technically no concept of a 'directory' or 'folder' but I need to check if a particular prefix exists.

Here is the way i'm detecting if a Blob exists which works fine:

```
public boolean doesFileExist(String bucket, String prefix) {
    Blob blob = storage.get(bucket, prefix);
    return blob != null;
}
```

This seems to work when using an actual filename with an extension. However, using this for something like `folder/` does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Folders do not exist in Cloud Storage. It is possible to create an object with the name 'folder/` which is what some software tools do to emulate folders. Cloud Storage is a flat namespace. The files `folderA/file1` and `folderB/file1` exist at the same level. If the object `folderA/file1` exists, then the prefixes will contain `folderA` but this is not a real folder in the file system convention. The `/` character is a usable character in Cloud Storage namespace and only has special meaning to your software.

Comment: ```Iterable<Blob> blobs = storage.list("gcpBucket", Storage.BlobListOption.prefix("gcpFolderPath")).iterateAll();```

If you get any blobs then the folder exists otherwise not.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @DougStevenson for the suggestion! I was able to get it working with this:

```
public boolean doesFileExist(String bucket, String prefix) {
    Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucket, BlobListOption.prefix(prefix), BlobListOption.pageSize(1));
    return blobs.getValues().iterator().hasNext();
}
```

Comment: Remember that folder doesn't exist!! it's only a file path metadata. If there is file in a part of the path (in a "folder") the "folder" exists.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Cloud Storage List API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) to query for all files with a shared prefix.  If you find any files at all, then that means it exists.  You will want to use the [list()](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Bucket.html#list-com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BlobListOption...-) method and pass a set of [BlobListOption](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.BlobListOption.html) that specify the prefix, and perhaps just a page size of 1 for efficiency.